# Simian excludes option

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, simian

I am having some issues configuring the options for Simian

Currently I have `<buildArgs>-includes=**/*.cs   -formatter=xml:build\log\simian.xml -failOnDuplication</buildArgs>`

I would like to add an -excludes option to exclude all files in a subfolder of the current directory, called branches.

I have tried several permutations, but keep getting 'Missing filespec'. I don't really understand the semantics of the pattern, and cant find any examples

TIA

**UPDATE**

I have tried these options

-excludes `**/branches/*.cs` (missing filespec)

-excludes `/branches/**/*.cs` (missing filespec)

I am interpreting ** to mean any folder recursively under the current base directory, or the path passed in, but the pattern seems to work differently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
simian-2.3.33.exe -includes=**\*.cs -excludes=branches\**\*.cs
```